# How to target the first character of a word using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javacript, and I want to know how to target the first character of the word `test`, and change the size of it using Javascript.

This is my code

```
<div id="logo">
    <style>
        #logo{
            transition: 0.3s ease;
        }
    </style>
<h1 onmousemove="move()" onmouseout="out()">test</h1>
<script>
    function move(){
        document.getElementById("logo").style.color = "red";     
    }
    move();
    function out(){
        document.getElementById("logo").style.color = "black";
    }
    out();
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi prof channel, you need to add css to your javascript script. Chris Riebschlager just added the css selector who will be able to make changes with the first character.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `::first-letter` CSS selector:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

https://caniuse.com/#search=first-letter

Answer (score 2):

Here is pure JS solution:

```
let t = document.querySelector('h1').textContent;
t = t[0].toUpperCase() + t.substring(1);
document.querySelector('h1').textContent = t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create CSS class and append it to your div.

CSS:

```
.ucfirst {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('logo').classList.add('ucfirst');
```

To remove class, simply call "remove" instead of "add".